# Modulus with float in coroutine

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

Im trying to do a coroutine that sets the character to hurt mode for a persiod. During this period i want it to flash. Im not familiar with modulus but i tried to use it to flip the sprite renderer every 10 or so cycles. But i get really weird values, is it cause its a float? How should i do this in unity?

```
public IEnumerator Hurt_cr (float sec, Vector2 attackPosition, float force)
        {
                isHurt = true;

                AddForceAtPosition (attackPosition, force);

                SpriteRenderer sprite = GetComponent< SpriteRenderer> ();
                float t = Time.deltaTime;

                while (t < sec) {

                        if ((t % 10) == 0) {

                                print ("sprite on :  " + sprite.enabled);
                                sprite.enabled = !sprite.enabled;
                        }

                        yield return null;
                        t += Time.deltaTime;
                }

                isHurt = false;
        }
```

Comment: I added an int cast or it might not work as expected. Now it's correct.

Comment: I added a `flashes--` I forgot earlier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use a coroutine, it's totally useless. Put this into Update:

```
sprite.enabled = ((int)(Time.time / 10)) % 2 == 0;
```

EDIT: added `(int)` cast for good measure.

EDIT 2: to have it flash a fixed number of times

Add the class propery:

```
public int flashes = 0;
private bool flashingLastFrame = false;
```

In Update count the flashes, if any:

```
bool flashingNow;

if (flashes > 0)
{
    flashingNow = ((int)(Time.time / 10)) % 2 == 0;

    if (flashingNow != flashingLastFrame)
    {
        flashingLastFrame = flashingNow;
        sprite.enabled = flashingNow;
        flashes--; // forgot this to make it stop
    }
}
```

To have it flash 3 times set from the outside:

```
obj.flashes = 6;
```

Or add a convenience method:

```
public void Flash(int times)
{
    flashes = times * 2;
}
```

EDIT 3: For super-fast flashing:

```
if (flashes > 0)
{
    flashingLastFrame = !flashingLastFrame;
    sprite.enabled = flashingLastFrame;
    flashes--;
}
```

Comment: Why is coroutine useless? In the unity documentation it seems quite recommended. Also id like to know what i was doing wrong with my try at modulus. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Look dont worry. I always accept an answer that helps. I am very gratefull for all you peps who help out in the forums. 

I dont get it. Doesnt that make the renderer flip back and forth all the time? I jus want it to do it for a short time. Seems to me that your code makes it flash constantly.

Comment: Actually i put it in the update and it doesnt do anything usefull. The renderer is disabled all the time.

Comment: With the (int) it works but / 10 is waaay to long. I set it to 0.2 and its also to slow. But still, its switching on every update. I want it to be for just a sec whenever the player is hurt.

Comment: seriously, that seems way more complicated then a coroutine. Or maybe not complicated, but i dont like to add 3 more members just to make the character flash if not nescesary. I just dont get why not do it with a coroutine.

Comment: The coroutine will be executed in a separate thread. This is not cost effective for such a small task. But you can implement it in a coroutine if you think you have to, I'd just not recommend it. Still, I'm a nobody and can't really teach anything to anybody :)

Comment: Thats not even true. You just tought me how i can use modulus to make stuff happen in cycles. Im very happy about that.  :)

Comment: @Pid `executed in a separate thread` is not correct. `Coroutines` are executed from the main thread.  See [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Don't they run in a separate thread? They might be executed (started) from the main thread, but they run in separate parallel threads themselves. This is what I meant, maybe the wording was confusing. I can fix that...

Comment: @Pid They do not.  You can dump the thread id to verify.  They are not asynchronous, as specified in the link in my last comment, as they run after all `Updates` are finished.  You can verify this as well by putting a blocking loop in your coroutine.

Comment: I will investigate as soon I have the time :) Thanks for the link!